# Passing variable to Flask from Javascript and then loading template

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

In my Flask app--I'm pretty new to Flask--, I'm getting the values for client's latitude and longitude with Javascript and then passing a formatted string to a flask view. The view is supposed to pass the string to an online API and obtain a JSON object. It then converts it to a dictionary and displays certain values on a new page. I'm having trouble with loading the page from the view after I pass it the variables from the Javasctipt function. I know that it returns a result (I tried using Javascript's `alert`to display the resulting `html`), but `return rendered_template()` doesn't load the new page for some reason. I wonder if that's even possible to achieve. Thanks.

Javascript:

```
function getLocation(){ 
    if("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(transferFile);
    }
}   

function transferFile(position){
    var start = 'lat=';
    var result = start.concat(position.coords.latitude, '&lon=',     position.coords.longitude, '&format=json');
    $.get(
    url="phony",
    data= result, 
    success=function(data) {
        ;
    }
);
```

}

And here's the Flask part:

```
@app.route('/phony')
def phony():
    query = request.query_string
    url = <link to API> + query
    location_dict = requests.get(url).json()
    return render_template("phony.html", location_data = location_dict)
```

Comment: Check "location_dict" is getting converted into dict as context obj for template without any issues.

Comment: You are making the request using Ajax. You have to update the page's content in the success callback. If you want the new page to load automatically you need to let the browser submit the form.

Comment: Murali, it does, I've checked that. @dirn could you explain how to do that with a code snippet, I'm pretty new to web development.

Answer (score 1):

Your current call to `$.get` doesn't do anything with the result in the success callback

```
success: function(data) {
  ;
}
```

`data` contains the output from `render_template('phone.html', location_data=location_dict)`. You need to add it to the page.

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#some-selector').html(data);
}
```

That will replace the contents of an element matching `#some-selector` with the output. If the output contains a new HTML document (i.e., it's wrapped in an html tag), you'll want to replace the entire DOM. You can do that with something like

```
success: function(data) {
  $('html').replaceWith(data);
}
```

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Comment: It contains the html page I'm trying to display, I checked with `alert`

Comment: Does it contain the html tag?

Comment: yes, it contains the tags. I found somewhat of a solution. I use `replaceWith()` to insert the target page within one of the current page's `<div>`'s, which accomplishes what I need. I'd love to figure out why `$('html').replaceWith(data);` doesn't work.